# How to fix: Connection Failed [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]User 'ODBC' has exceeded the max connections per hour resource

Tags: mysql

Error Code is as follows (screenshot linked) Error Connection Failed [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]User 'ODBC' has exceeded the max connections per hour resource

I linked my settings also. MySql 5.3 Unicode Driver.

How do I get around this? I am running MS Queries off of Excel, I never get this issue. Thanks.

https://pasteboard.co/H3vBpqE.png
https://pasteboard.co/H3vCCa4.png

Comment: Does [this DBA.SE answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/156393/129378) help? Essentially you've exceeded the number of connections that MySQL allows for your user. You may have Excel open multiple times, or maybe Excel crashed and is holding a connection open, etc.

Comment: It does not help. I have 5.3 and cannot update it in my current environment. How do I manage and "kill" my OBDC connections?

Comment: The easiest way is to restart MySQL. Are you able to do that? You can also try to reboot the client machines, but your MySQL server should be definitive.

Comment: This MySQL doc about [setting account resource limits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-resources.html) might help as well. It looks like you can actually define the maximum number of times a user can connect within an hour.